# How to code Matlab in VSCode via Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, matlab, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter kernel is running well since I can do Matlab jobs using a 'browser jupyter notebook' as well as when I was coding in Python. And I can also code Python in my notebooks via VSCode. But it seems weird that I can't code Matlab in notebooks via VSCode. Are there anything that I didn't notice which leads me to this error? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I tried several approaches.

- Adding Matlab and Python kernel path into VSCode "settings.json" file -> didn't work.
- Running VSCode with admin rights -> didn't work.
- Running "jupyter notebook" and "activate jmatlab" (aka matlab_kernel) with the VSCode terminal -> didn't work.

So, there are **two solutions**.

1. Launch VSCode using Anaconda Navigator.

[image: Launch VSCode using Anaconda Navigator]

After selecting the jmatlab environment, select one of the two Matlab kernels and run the Matlab code.

[image: Matlab and Python kernel]

2. Launch VSCode with the command line.

   - Open terminal (cmd).
   - Activate the jmatlab environment anywhere you want -> *C:> activate jmatlab*
   - Launch VSCode by simple typing -> *(jmatlab)C:> code*
   - Test your Matlab code.